# Jquery POST not writing integer array into MVC controller parameter

Tags: jquery, post, model-view-controller, controller

For some reason I'm having trouble getting my integer array values properly posted into my MVC controller.  I've looked at many posts regarding this topic
but so far I have not been able to get this working.

My caller looks like this:

```
 $scope.openRollUpReport = function (inItem) {

        var IssueIDs = [];
        IssueIDs.push(1);
        IssueIDs.push(4);

        var request = $.ajax({
            traditional: true,
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(IssueIDs),
            datatype: 'json'
        });
    };
```

My controller method looks like this:

```
 [System.Web.Http.Route("Api/Report/RollUpReport/")]
 [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
 public void RollUpReport(int[] IssueIDs)
 {

 }
```

I'm successfully calling the controller method.  However, IssueIDs looks like this:  {int[0]}

Also, I noticed in IE Developer tools the Request Body looks like this:
[1,4].  I'm sure it's something basic I'm missing.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Pete

Thanks Kevin,  I tried this:

```
 var IssueIDs = [];
        IssueIDs.push(1);
        IssueIDs.push(4);

        var jsonData = { IssueIDs: IssueIDs };

        var request = $.ajax({
            traditional: true,
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
            datatype: 'json'
        });
```

but I'm still getting this in the server method:  {int[0]}

I decided to change this to just simply POST a comma-delimited string and then parse server-side.  This is what I ended up with:

```
   $scope.openRollUpReport = function (inItem) {

        var IssueIDs = '1,5,9,12';

        var request = $.ajax({
            traditional: true,
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: '=' + IssueIDs
        });
    };
```

Server Side:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
 public HttpResponseMessage RollUpReport([FromBody] string IssueIDs)
 {
     HttpResponseMessage result;
     result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     return result;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin,  I tried as you suggested but I'm still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to change this to just simply POST a comma-delimited string and then parse server-side.  This is what I ended up with:

```
   $scope.openRollUpReport = function (inItem) {

        var IssueIDs = '1,5,9,12';

        var request = $.ajax({
            traditional: true,
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: '=' + IssueIDs
        });
    };
```

Server Side:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
 public HttpResponseMessage RollUpReport([FromBody] string IssueIDs)
 {
     HttpResponseMessage result;
     result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON needs to name the IssueIds parameter, not just stringify an array directly.

```
var jsonData = { IssueIds: IssueIds };
$.ajax({ ... data: JSON.stringify(jsonData)});
```

Also, it's been a while, but I can't remember if you need an attribute for accepting JSON.